# wxpython button with stock icon but no text

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I am using wxPython and would like to create a button with a stock icon and no text. If I do

```
wx.Button(self,wx.ID_ADD)
```

I get a button with a plus sign icon and the word 'Add' beside it.

How can I get a button with only the icon ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, it looks like `wx.BU_NOTEXT` could work for this, but it actually doesn't because wxWidgets supposes that if this style is used, then the button is supposed to have a bitmap explicitly associated with it.

So the simplest fix is to actually do set this bitmap by calling `btn->SetBitmapLabel(wxArtProvider::GetBitmap(wxART_PLUS, wxART_MENU))` (this is C++, but should be easily translatable to Python too). If you do it like this, you don't need to use `wxID_ADD` as the button ID any more, but if you still want to keep using this ID, then you also need to use `wxBU_NOTEXT` to get rid of the stock text.

And, unlike stock buttons, which intentionally conform to the standard platform look and so may show the icon or not depending on the platform, this code will work the same everywhere.

Comment: On GTK, all I get is a blank button with nothing on it. On Windows and macOS, I've just realised the icons don't appear anyway - just the text. On those platforms `BU_NOTEXT` has no effect.

Comment: Oops, sorry for misleading you. I've updated/rewritten the answer.

Comment: I can confirm that works on GTK, macOS and Windows. In Python, I used `button = wx.Button(self,wx.ID_ANY, style=wx.BU_EXACTFIT)` and then `button.SetBitmapLabel(wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_PLUS, wx.ART_MENU))`. I added `BU_EXACTFIT` so the button is sized to fit the icon, otherwise it's rendered with a standard button width.

Comment: If you need one of the icons that doesn't come in the limited selection from `wx.ArtProvider`, e.g. the "select all" button that appears with `wx.ID_SELECTALL`, then you can use the GTK+ stock item ID, e.g., `button.SetBitmapLabel(wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap("gtk-select-all", wx.ART_MENU))` per https://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/classwx_art_provider.html#artprovider_identify